# Google Analytics for sites with SSL protected sections

Tags: google-analytics, https

Google Analytics account creation interface asks whether the URL of the site starts with HTTP or HTTPS. However my site is SSL protected in its payment pages only.

Is it possible to have GA cover everything, or do I have to choose between SSL sections and non SSL sections ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer; yes.

Just add the http url for the website,

link the analytics script file with // and not http:// and it will "just work".